# I want to execute the shell script on my local hard drive on an EC2 instance using SSM & the node API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

From the console, it looks like I need to upload the script to S3 and then run it from there.  Uploading the shell script to S3 is easy:

```
const scriptFile = "./path/to/test.sh";
const scriptFilename = "test.sh";
console.log("Uploading " + scriptFile + " to S3...");
let fileContentsToUpload = fs.readFileSync(scriptFile, "utf8");
let uploadResult = await this.s3.upload({
  Bucket: "myBucket", Key: "/someDir/" + scriptFilename,
  Body: fileContentsToUpload, ContentType: "text/x-shellscript"
}).promise();
```

I don't understand what I use for the parameters for SSM.  Do I then create a new document?

Here are the contents of my "test.sh" shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo This a test | tee /tmp/testOutput.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  There is no need to create a new document. I can see from the EC2 console that the script location is shared as parameters. So here's the code:

```
const params = {
  DocumentName: "AWS-RunRemoteScript",
  InstanceIds: ["i-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
  Parameters: {
    sourceType: ["S3"],
    sourceInfo: [JSON.stringify({
      path: uploadResult.Location
    })],
    commandLine: [scriptFilename],
    workingDirectory:["/tmp"]
  },
  ServiceRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::<your-aws-account-id>:role/<someRole>"  // Make sure this role has access to get files from S3
};
console.log("Executing on the server:", CommonUtils.stringify(params));
let sendCommandResult = await this.ssm.sendCommand(params).promise();
console.log("Result of running build script: " + JSON.stringify(sendCommandResult));
```

Then, if you login to the AWS SSM console, go to "Run Command" on the left and then click on the "Command History" tab, you can read all about the results of running your command.

[image]